# Groovy Eclipse Autoformat?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, code-formatting

Using Eclipse 3.6 and Groovy 2.0.1.20100319-1100-e35-RELEASE, auto-format does nothing. That is, for a given groovy file, `Source > Format` does nothing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running Groovy-Eclipse for Eclipse 3.5 in Eclipse 3.6, so that is why it is broken.  I'm surprised that you are even able to install it.  You need to install a snapshot version of Groovy-Eclipse for 3.6.  Only available viz zip file:

http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.6/

Download the archive and point your p2 installer to the zip.  You can install the 3.6 stream of Groovy-Eclipse.  Formatting should then work.

If you are still having problems, then look at your error log and post any relevant exceptions here (but, I'm guessing that everything should be fine).